# What's the meaning of "Before the world fell at our feet"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

Adele in her song says

> Before the world fell at our feet

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adele is talking about a time before she became successful and admired.

> **have the world at your feet**
>
> *British English*
>
> to be ​extremely ​successful and ​admired by a ​large ​number of ​people

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-the-world-at-your-feet

It's a metaphor where *the world* simply means *lots of people*. A variation of the above phrase is *to have the world fall at your feet*. Think of adoring people, prostrated in front of you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe in this interpretation because she sings "our world". I think the meaning is "break down". Maybe for her the world is falling on knees, but not for the other person who remains in the little town... Their common basis fell down and was broken.